# Upgrading to 21.04 leads to "screen lock requires gnome display manager" and random freezes while inactive

Tags: gnome, upgrade, lightdm, 21.04, display-manager

I upgraded my workstation (AMD threadripper + NVidia RTX 3080) from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04 with `do-release-upgrade`.

After the upgrade when I logged in, there was a popup message saying "screen lock requires gnome display manager". Furthermore, all the icons on my desktop were duplicated, e.g. two recycling bin icons, with one non-functional.

The worst thing though, is that it's now randomly freezing. The mouse/keyboard and even ssh becomes unresponsive. This seems to occur when nobody is using it... which makes me wonder if it's related to the screen lock popup message, but maybe that's a red herring.

I think I solved the duplicated icons problem by uninstalling Nautilus, so don't think that's related.

I've tried un/re-installing gnome-display-manager / lightdm but that doesn't seem to have made a difference (not 100% certain I did it 'right').

Any guesses? How to I even figure out what might be causing the freezes? What would be the best way to just to do a fresh install without losing apps etc? Home directories are stored on a seperate drive and mounted onto /home.

Answer (score 2):

Icons duplicated due to second "Desktop Icons" extension. To fix that, disable one in "GNOME Extensions" app. The newest one is called "Desktop Icons NG (DING)".

The problem with "screen lock requires gnome display manager" I solved by reconfiguring gdm by running "sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3" and selecting "gdm3" instead of "lightdm". It changed looks of login screen after reboot but now it is possible to lock desktop.